# How to discover desktop applications on Windows and Mac OS (Linux .desktop files equivalent)

Tags: windows, macos, desktop

On Linux, you can discover "registered" applications by searching for `.desktop` files in the relevant directories.

How can a program (eg a launcher) discover the equivalent information (application names, path and shortcut image) on Windows and OS X?

Comment: Did you mean the shortcuts link in desktops? Windows and macOS are different. Choose any one.

Comment: I realize they are different, I'm asking about both.

Comment: Here is the details for Windows [Shell Links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/links).

Answer (score 1):

On macOS applications (or those designed to run by launching them with a mouse) are designated by the extension ".app"

The problem with that is that even if if you have "show all filename extensions" checked in Finder .app extensions are *still* invisible... Unless you use Terminal and get a directory listing.

So if you are so inclined you can search for anything in root and subdirectories that ends in ".app" to list your Applications. But I'd go with something simpler. Open the /Applications folder. Everything there is an application or a folder containing an application.

OK so not *everything* as some apps store support and readme files with the application rather than within the .app bundle or in one of the Application Support directories or in the case of documentation, in the ~/[username]/Documents/ folder.

As for other applications designed to run from a Shell... Well those are stored all over the place. And as macOS is based on BSD Unix many command line apps are stored in common Unix locations. The location of which will be left up to people more curious than myself. I don't *care* where they are, as long as they work.

Comment: Thanks. For regular shell applications I guess you can just iterate all directories in $PATH similar to Linux.